# IMediaControl.Stop hangs on second monitor

Tags: winapi, video, directshow

'Why IMediaControl.Stop is hanging' seems to be a frequently asked question. Now I experienced this with a particularity: If the application that runs the filtergraph is located on the first monitor everything goes like clockwork. Also stopping the filtergraph works w/o problems. But when the application is moved to the second Monitor a call of IMediaControl.Stop() never returns and the software hangs.
 Any clue what the reason could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video Mixing Renderer (VMR-7) filter can be set up with [`IVMRMonitorConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390481) interface for specific monitor. If you effectively use it on a different monitor it restarts the graph so that it could re-configure itself during such restart. That is, there is a Stop/Pause/Run cycle. Your freeze is taking place during this transition because of another faulty filter. Effectively it is the same sort of problem as frequently asked, and the same recipe applies: you need to check call stacks at the time of the freeze, identify deadlock cause and faulty filters, resolve the found problem. Same applies to VMR-9 filter.

That is, a Stop call is expected behavior. Stop freeze is not so much different from other stop freezes: it's not video renderer that freezes but another filter which handles stop transition incorrectly.

See also:

- [Stopping IMediaControl never ends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529895/868014)